# Why is splitting a Rust's std::collections::LinkedList O(n)?

Tags: linked-list, rust, time-complexity

The `.split_off` method on `std::collections::LinkedList` is described as having a O(n) time complexity. From the ([docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.LinkedList.html#method.split_off)):

> ```
> pub fn split_off(&mut self, at: usize) -> LinkedList<T>
> ```
>
> Splits the list into two at the given index. Returns everything after the given index, including the index.
>
> This operation should compute in O(n) time.

Why not O(1)?

I know that linked lists are not trivial in Rust. There are several resources going into the how's and why's like [this book](http://cglab.ca/~abeinges/blah/too-many-lists/book/) and [this article](https://rcoh.me/posts/rust-linked-list-basically-impossible/) among several others, but I haven't got the chance to dive into those or the standard library's source code yet.

Is there a concise explanation about the extra work needed when splitting a linked list in (safe) Rust?

Is this the only way? And if not why was this implementation chosen?

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes please (two downvotes at the time I wrote this comment)? This question seems absolutely fine to me.

Comment: *but I haven't got the chance* — so you haven't put *any* effort of your own into figuring out the answer on your own?

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt Not a downvoter, but I think there are two main reasons: first, the OP does not say why they believe it to be possible to implement `split_off` in O(1) time, so it's not possible to guess at the source of the confusion; and second, the question is worded as if it's blaming Rust's standard library for an inefficient implementation when in reality this is just how all linked lists work.

Comment: I think if the question had been phrased "I have heard that splitting a linked list is an O(1) operation; why is `split_off` O(n)?" it would probably not have been downvoted. (And it could have been tagged [tag:language-agnostic] to boot)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The method `LinkedList::split_off(&mut self, at: usize)` first has to traverse the list from the start (or the end) to the position `at`, which takes O(min(`at`, n - `at`)) time. The actual split off is a constant time operation (as you said).  And since this *min()* expression is confusing, we just replace it by `n` which is legal. Thus: O(n).

---

Why was the method designed like that? The problem goes deeper than this particular method: **most of the `LinkedList` API in the standard library is not really useful.**

Due to its cache unfriendliness, a linked list is often a bad choice to store sequential data. But linked lists have a few nice properties which make them the best data structure for a few, rare situations. These nice properties include:

- Inserting an element in the middle in O(1), *if you already have a pointer to that position*
- Removing an element from the middle in O(1), *if you already have a pointer to that position*
- Splitting the list into two lists at an arbitrary position in O(1), *if you already have a pointer to that position*

Notice anything? The linked list is designed for situations where you already have a pointer to the position that you want to do stuff at.

Rust's `LinkedList`, like many others, just store a pointer to the start and end. To have a pointer to an element inside the linked list, you need something like an `Iterator`. In our case, that's [`IterMut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/collections/linked_list/struct.IterMut.html). An iterator over a collection can function like a pointer to a specific element and can be advanced carefully (i.e. not with a `for` loop). And in fact, there is `IterMut::insert_next` which allows you to insert an element in the middle of the list in O(1). Hurray!

But this method is unstable. And methods to remove the current element or to split the list off at that position are missing. Why? Because of the vicious circle that is:

- `LinkedList` lacks almost all features that make linked lists useful at all
- Thus (nearly) everyone recommends not to use it
- **Thus (nearly) no one uses `LinkedList`**
- **Thus (nearly) no one cares about improving it**
- Goto 1

Please note that are a few brave souls occasionally trying to improve the situations. There is [the tracking issue about `insert_next`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/27794), where people argue that `Iterator` might be the wrong concept to perform these O(1) operations and that we want something like a "cursor" instead. And [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/39148#issuecomment-273612068) someone suggested a bunch of methods to be added to `IterMut` (including `cut`!).

Now someone just has to write a nice RFC and someone needs to implement it. Maybe then `LinkedList` won't be nearly useless anymore.

**Edit 2018-10-25**: someone [did write an RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2570). Let's hope for the best!

**Edit 2019-02-21**: the RFC was accepted! [Tracking issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/58533).

Answer (score 8):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question, but in a linked list, the links of each node have to be followed to proceed to the next node. If you want to get to the third node, you start at the first, follow its link to the second, then finally arrive at the third.

This traversal's complexity is proportional to the target node index *n* because *n* nodes are processed/traversed, so it's a linear O(*n*) operation, not a constant time O(1) operation. The part where the list is "split off" is of course constant time, but the overall split operation's complexity is dominated by the dominant term O(*n*) incurred by getting to the split-off point node before the split can even be made.

One way in which it could be O(1) would be if a pointer existed to the node after which the list is split off, but that is different from specifying a target node index. Alternatively, an index could be kept mapping the node index to the corresponding node pointer, but it would be extra space and processing overhead in keeping the index updated in sync with list operations.

Answer (score 5):

> ```
> pub fn split_off(&mut self, at: usize) -> LinkedList<T>
> ```
>
> Splits the list into two at the given index. Returns everything after the given index, including the index.
>
> This operation should compute in O(n) time.

The documentation is either:

- unclear, if `n` is supposed to be the index,
- pessimistic, if `n` is supposed to be the length of the list (the usual meaning).

The proper complexity, as can be seen in the implementation, is O(min(at, n - at)) (whichever is smaller). Since `at` must be smaller than `n`, the documentation is correct that O(n) is a bound on the complexity (reached for `at = n / 2`), however such a large bound is unhelpful.

That is, the fact that `list.split_off(5)` takes the same time if `list.len()` is 10 or 1,000,000 is quite important!

As to why this complexity, this is an inherent consequence of the structure of doubly-linked list. There is no O(1) indexing operation in a linked-list, after all. The operation implemented in C, C++, C#, D, F#, ... would have the exact same complexity.

*Note: I encourage you to write a pseudo-code implementation of a linked-list with the `split_off` operation; you'll realize this is the best you can get without altering the data-structure to be something else.*

Comment: The [documentation for `std::collections`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/index.html#sequences) does have the more precise O(min(i, n-i)).